# AngularJS. strange behaviour of filter in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Why does AngularJS call the filter in ng-repeat so many times?

for example:

Controller:

```
$scope.data = [1,2,3];
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    {{ item | mySuperFilter }}
</div>
```

filter:

```
.filter('mySuperFilter', function(){
    return function(v) {
        console.log(v);
        return v;
    }
});
```

and result in console:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Why angular does it?

PS: sorry for my english

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does \`filter\` trigger some many times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309755/why-does-filter-trigger-some-many-times)

Comment: sorry, i dont find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your data object an array of objects, rather than an array of integers as you have now. Like this…

Controller:

```
$scope.data = [
  {value: 1},
  {value: 2},
  {value: 3}];
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
  {{ item.value | mySuperFilter }}
</div>
```